# How to create exit button in Flash application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm creating a Flash Application that will be exported in `exe` format and it's not going to run in browser. I want to add an exit button inside stage but I don't know how to do that with ActionScript 3.

I remember that it was possible with `fscommand` in ActionScript 2 but it's not working in AS3.

I've searched everywhere but everyone is trying to close a popup or tab or window all in browser environment not a Flash app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why would use a .exe format when you can now export as3 application as AIR? 
BUT
If you still want the exe, I think that this will work

```
 import flash.system.fscommand;

 //Then you can use the following function for the button click handler:

 private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
      fscommand("quit");
 }
```

If you decide to try the AIR solution, this is the command

```
 import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
 nativeApp.nativeApplication.exit();
```

Comment: Umm, actually I have no idea about AIR and I'm a in hurry for completing my project, I will take a look at it later.

Comment: Can AIR apps run on Mac as well? Do they need to have AIR installed or can you do it form the Flash IDE?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau yes, AIR app run on Mac too. About your second question, I don't understand it completely sorry.

Comment: Correction: Last line of code: From `nativeApp.nativeApplication.exit();` To Correct code  `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(); `

Answer (score 4):

It's still an `fscommand`, but the syntax is different:

```
import flash.system.fscommand;

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, closeApp);

function closeApp(event:MouseEvent):void {
    fscommand("quit");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

System.exit(0); should close a desktop application?

Comment: This also works. You'll need to `import flash.system.System;` for it to work, of course.

Comment: Thank you. `System.exit(0)` and `fscommand("quit")` are both working.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 import flash.system.fscommand;

 function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
 fscommand("quit");
 }

 btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function exitAdobe (event:MouseEvent): void {

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();

}
bt_exit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exitAdobe);

//A melhor forma que encontrei...
```

Comment: Format your code correctly (must be pushed four spaces to the right) and try to use English.